# ggplot2 displays wrong colors with manual scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, bar-chart, scale-color-manual

I am trying to plot my data with manual color scale based on values. However the colors that are displayed nowhere near correspond to the values that I provide.
My data looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 100 x 2
   chunk      avg  
   <dbl>    <dbl>  
 1     0  0.0202
 2     1  0.0405
 3     2  0.0648
 4     3  0.0405
 5     4  0.0283
 6     5 -0.00806
 7     6 -0.0526
 8     7 -0.0364
 9     8 -0.00810
10     9  0.0243
# ... with 90 more rows
```

Then I pipe it to ggplot2:

```
data %>%
    ggplot(
        aes(
            chunk,
            avg,
            fill = cut(
                avg,
                c(-Inf, -0.01, 0.01, Inf)
            )
        )
    ) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", show.legend = FALSE) +
    scale_color_manual(
        values = c(
            "(-Inf, -0.01)" = "red",
            "[-0.01, 0.01]" = "yellow",
            "(0.01, Inf)" = "green"
        )
    )
```

As you can see, I want to color my bars based on values, below -0.01 red, above 0.01 green and bettween - yellow.

This is the result I receive:

[image: failed plot]

What am I missing?

Comment: Try `scale_fill_manual( ...`

Comment: If I change to `scale_fill_manual` I get no chart at all. If I do the opposite and change `fill` to `color` in `aes` I get gray bars.

Comment: ... the issue when switching to `scale_fill_manual` is that the default labels returned by `cut` have (almost) no spaces after the commas, i.e. `cut(runif(10, -1 ,1), c(-Inf, -0.01, 0.01, Inf))` gives `Levels: (-Inf,-0.01] (-0.01,0.01] (0.01, Inf]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting different colours *I think* is because `ggplot` isn't automatically making a connection between the colours you have supplied and the groups you have supplied. I'm not 100% sure why this is the case, but I can offer a solution.

You can create a new column in the data before you send it to `ggplot` for plotting. We will call it `colour_group` but you can call it anything. We populate this new column based on the values of `avg` (I have made sample data as you haven't supplied all of yours). We use `ifelse()` which tests a condition against the data, and returns a value based on if the `test` is `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

In the below code, `colour_group = ifelse(avg < -0.01, 'red', NA)` may be read aloud as: "If my value of avg is less than -0.01, make the value for the `colour_group` column 'red', otherwise make it `NA`". For subsequent lines, we want the `FALSE` result to keep the results already in the `colour_group` column - the ones made on the previous lines.

```
# make sample data
tibble(
  chunk = 1:100,
  avg = rnorm(100, 1, 1)
) %>%
  {. ->> my_data}


# make the new 'colour_group' column
my_data %>%
  mutate(
    colour_group = ifelse(avg < -0.01, 'red', NA),
    colour_group = ifelse(avg > 0.01, 'green', colour_group),
    colour_group = ifelse(avg > -0.01 & avg < 0.01 , 'yellow', colour_group),
  ) %>%
  {. ->> my_data_modified}
```

Now we can plot the data, and specify that we want to use the `colour_group` column as the `fill` aesthetic. When specifying `scale_fill_manual`, we then tell `ggplot` that if we have the value of `green` in the `colour_group` column, we want the bar to be a green colour, and so on for the other colours.

```
my_data_modified %>%
  ggplot(aes(chunk, avg, fill = colour_group))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', show.legend = FALSE)+
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c('green' = 'green', 'red' = 'red', 'yellow' = 'yellow')
  )
```

[image]

It is slightly confusing, in a way having to specify the colour twice. However, we could specify the values of `colour_group` as anything, such as 1, 2, 3 or low, med, high. In this instance, you would do the same code but modify the `ifelse` statements, and change `scale_fill_manual` to match these values. For example:

```
my_data %>%
  mutate(
    colour_group = ifelse(avg < -0.01, 'low', NA),
    colour_group = ifelse(avg > 0.01, 'high', colour_group),
    colour_group = ifelse(avg > -0.01 & avg < 0.01 , 'med', colour_group),
  ) %>%
  {. ->> my_data_modified}

my_data_modified %>%
  ggplot(aes(chunk, avg, fill = colour_group))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', show.legend = FALSE)+
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c('high' = 'green', 'low' = 'red', 'med' = 'yellow')
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If in aes you put 'color=' then you must put scale_color_manual. But if you put fill, as you ve actually done, then the command is scale_fill_manual

Comment: Hi Nacho,
Welcome to SO! This answer is a great start... could you use Kolin's original code and give an example where they get the desired color mapping? 

Also, it's always helpful to format answers, e.g. if you're referencing code to wrap in "\`", e.g. `scale_fill_manual()`

Comment: If I change to `scale_fill_manual` I get no chart at all. If I do the opposite and change `fill` to `color` in `aes` I get gray bars. So no matching pair gives me the desired result.